# Assign an namespace to an XML document without loading the XML

Tags: c#, xml

We are working with very large XML files at our company (100 Mb to 3 Gb and more).
Now, the documents that are delivered to our system out delivered without a namespace, which are system cannot handle, we do need a namespace in the document.

What we do currently is loading the XML document and through an XLST transformation we're setting the namesapce.

Off course, loading a Xml Document through the following code:

```
loadedDoc.LoadXml(xmlData);
```

takes a very long time when using files that are that large. In the past, we were dealing with rather small files so it was never an issue.

Does anybode knows a solution on how I can set a namespace in an XML document in the most performant way?

Kind regards

Comment: If I understand correctly you are loading the xml, doing xslt to set a namespace and then reopening it to perform deserialization. Why not use directly `XmlReaderSettings` and `XmlAttributeOverrides`? Or adjust your deserialization classes to not have to perform this additional task?

Comment: You can read file as a text (will be much faster than xml-parsing, but as slow as HDD require to read; HDD speed can't be overcomed physically) and only replace lines with namespaces.